# Как выводить поля в стандартном интерфейсе?

Tags: django-admin, django

Всем привет! Подскажите, описанные поля необходимо в стандартном интерфейсе `django` выводить, если `is_deleted=0`

```
class Users(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    basic_account = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    actual_address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Второй шаг учебного урока](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02.html#customize-the-admin-form)